# PHP if GET using if isset

Tags: php, mysql, get

I am new to PHP and I would like to know the correct way to display error in index.php but only if there are errors otherwise it does nothing.

The page index.php send the form to login.php if there are errors it return the error to index.php like this:

```
index.php?error=1
```

Then in index I have the follow code but it feels like the page got slow

```
<?php
if ($_GET['error']==1){echo "We show error 1 ...";}
if ($_GET['error']==2){echo "We show error 2 ...";}
if ($_GET['error']==3){echo "We show error 3 ...";}

?>
```

How can I fix it the correct way? Some uses the if isset but I dont know how to use this funtion it give me errors

Comment: How did you try to use the `isset`?

Comment: I would be extremely surprised if the code you added slowed the page by more than a few milliseconds.

Comment: I want to use the isset but I am new and dont know how to start and end the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you have repetition like you have presented in your example, try using a `function` or a storage `array`. Though your code probably isn't going much slower, try something like this:

```
<?php
// List of errors. If you do it this way, you can keep
// adding errors without adding if/else
$error[1]= "We show error 1 ...";
$error[2]= "We show error 2 ...";
$error[3]= "We show error 3 ...";

// Check if set
if(isset($_GET['error']) && isset($error[$_GET['error']]))
    echo $error[$_GET['error']];
?>
```

Comment: Really nice one. Learned something new. Thanks a lot

Comment: just for future users commig here the code is missing a { before echo

Comment: Programming for you, three different ways to solve the same problem.  This method is definitely useful when you use a large application and have specific error codes.

Comment: @Rasclatt, you could actually shorten this by using: `if (isset($error[$_GET['error']]))`

Comment: @Devon, that is true. You wouldn't really need a numeric check. I'll update.

Comment: I meant, you check if $_GET[error] inside $error[] is set.  That would avoid a NOTICE if $_GET['error'] is set to 4 for instance.

Comment: @Devon Oh an index notice. Yeah that is true. Man for such a short code, this has been a lot of work!

Answer (score 1):

isset isn't provided anywhere in your code, but this also presents an opportunity to introduce you to [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php).

```
if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
  switch($_GET['error']) {
     case 1:
         echo "We show error 1...";
         break;
     case 2:
         echo "We show error 2...";
         break;
     case 3:
         echo "We show error 3...";
         break;
  }
}
```

Instead of using different if's, you can combine it all into one switch.  This is similar to using elseif but neater (in my opinion).

Comment: new PHP?  Switch has been around since PHP 4, so a decade.

Answer (score 0):

`isset` in PHP from the documentation is to determine if a variable is set and is not NULL. Refer [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

This is how you can use it in your case.

Assuming the URL is something like `index.php?error=1`

Then you could use:

```
if( isset($_GET['error']) ){
    if( $_GET['error'] == 1 ) {echo 'Error 1!';}
    elseif( $_GET['error'] == 2 ) {echo 'Error 2!';}
    elseif( $_GET['error'] == 3 ) {echo 'Error 3!';}
}
```

Using `elseif` can terminate the execution once you reach any error code. For example, if you have `error=2` it will not check if the `error=3` thus makes the execution faster. But as Scopey mentioned above, the difference of execution time for this kind of thing is actually something that you don't have to worry.

Hope this helps. Thank you.

Comment: This one seems to work fine. I will take this answer. Just a small question. Do I need to set an "else" in the last code? Like if elseif elseif else ? Or will it work fine just like that?

Comment: If you just put `else` that means the any error code other than 1 & 2 (say 3 or 4 or 5 etc) will go into that block. But if you put `elseif` you will check other than error 1 and 2, IF error is 3 then show something.